# FFMPEG - mute or unmute audio from incoming stream while ffmpeg is running

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, ffmpeg, streaming

I got the following issue:

I want to be able to mute and unmute the audio from a ffmpeg stream whilst the ffmpeg is running. I was searching for a while now and wondered how you would do it. I read a lot on the internet but I wasn't finding the problem I searched for.

I only know now that you can do it with sendcmd or zmq filters but the API of ffmpeg for this to things are not getting me any further.

Can anybody explain me how to do it? If I understand correctly you have to insert the filter parameters into the running programm via `sendcmd` or `zmq` filters.

Here is what i have in a `.bat` to start ffmpeg:

`start cmd /K ffmpeg -i "rtsp://[IPADRESS]" -b:v 6000K -minrate 6000K -maxrate 6000K -vcodec copy  -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://[IPADRESS]`

Answer (score 0):

For interactively mute and unmute the audio, you may use [azmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-zmq_002c-azmq) filter with [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter.

For using interactive commands, we need a tool named `zmqsend`.
You may download `ffmpeg-tools.zip` Windows version from [here](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).
(For testing, I have extracted the tools to be in the same folder as ffmpeg.exe).

---

Add the following audio filter: `-af "azmq,volume@my=volume=1"` to your FFmpeg command.

- `volume@my` uses "interactive name" for the volume filter.
- `azmq` is required for allowing interactive commands for the audio filter that comes after `azmq` (interactive commands to the `volume` filter).

---

Here is a batch file that executes FFplay, and listens to FFmpeg RTMP stream:

```
start ffplay -listen 1 -timeout 10000 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
start ffmpeg -y -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=25000:size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -af "azmq,volume@my=volume=1" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test
```

The above commands stream synthetic audio and video (for testing).

The `ping` command is used for waiting few seconds before starting FFmpeg.
You may place the batch file in the same folder as ffmpeg.exe and zmqsend.exe

---

Execute the batch file...

For muting the audio, execute (from the console):

```
echo volume@my volume 0 | zmqsend
```

For unmuting the audio, execute:

```
echo volume@my volume 1 | zmqsend
```

---

There may be other methods, but the interactive commands subject is not well documented...